# boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket.read_some() stops working. No exception or errors detected

Tags: c++, sockets, c++17, boost-asio

I am currently debugging a server(win32/64) that utilizes Boost:asio 1.78.

The code is a blend of legacy, older legacy and some newer code. None of this code is mine. I can't answer for why something is done in a certain way. I'm just trying to understand why this is happening and hopefully fix it wo. rewriting it from scratch. This code has been running for years on 50+ servers with no errors. Just these 2 servers that missbehaves.

I have one client (dot.net) that is connected to two servers. Client is sending the same data to the 2 servers. The servers run the same code, as follows in code sect.

All is working well but now and then communications halts. No errors or exceptions on either end. It just halts. Never on both servers at the same time. This happens very seldom. Like every 3 months or less. I have no way of reproducing it in a debugger bc I don't know where to look for this behavior.

On the client side the socket appears to be working/open but does not accept new data. No errors is detected in the socket.

Here's a shortened code describing the functions. I want to stress that I can't detect any errors or exceptions during these failures. Code just stops at "m_socket->read_some()".

Only solution to "unblock" right now is to close the socket manually and restart the acceptor. When I manually close the socket the read_some method returns with error code so I know it is inside there it stops.

Questions:

1. What may go wrong here and give this behavior?
2. What parameters should I log to enable me to determine what is happening, and from where.

main code:

```
std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> io_service_is = std::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service>();
auto is_work = std::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service::work>(*io_service_is.get());

auto acceptor = std::make_shared<TcpAcceptorWrapper>(*io_service_is.get(), port);
acceptor->start();

auto threadhandle = std::thread([&io_service_is]() {io_service_is->run();});
```

TcpAcceptorWrapper:

```
void start(){
    m_asio_tcp_acceptor.open(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4());
    m_asio_tcp_acceptor.bind(boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), m_port));
    m_asio_tcp_acceptor.listen();
    start_internal();
}
void start_internal(){
    m_asio_tcp_acceptor.async_accept(m_socket, [this](boost::system::error_code error) { /* Handler code */ });
}
```

Handler code:

```
m_current_session = std::make_shared<TcpSession>(&m_socket);
std::condition_variable condition;
std::mutex mutex;
bool stopped(false);

m_current_session->run(condition, mutex, stopped);              
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    condition.wait(lock, [&stopped] { return stopped; });
}
```

TcpSession runner:

```
void run(std::condition_variable& complete, std::mutex& mutex, bool& stopped){
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    
    std::thread([this, self, &complete, &mutex, &stopped]() {
        { // mutex scope

            // Lock and hold mutex from tcp_acceptor scope
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

            while (true) {
                std::array<char, M_BUFFER_SIZE> buffer;

                try {
                    boost::system::error_code error;

                    /* Next call just hangs/blocks but only rarely. like once every 3 months or more seldom */
                    std::size_t read = m_socket->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer, M_BUFFER_SIZE), error);

                    if (error || read == -1) {
                        // This never happens
                        break;
                    }
                    // inside this all is working
                    process(buffer);

                } catch (std::exception& ex) {
                    // This never happens
                    break;
                } catch (...) {
                    // Neither does this
                    break;
                }
            }
            stopped = true;
        } // mutex released
        complete.notify_one();
    }).detach();
}
```

Comment: What does "mutex scope" mean? Are you holding the lock the entire time?

Comment: @sehe yes, I'm holding it back until session returns via condition-variable. The mutex gives me single access to bool until break.

Comment: Inside .run() method is some logging code and the thread described in "Session runner"
The mutex in the handler is passed in and then is held inside run(), inside the detatched thread. When the detached thread exits the mutex is released and conditional_variable is notified. The Handler then locks the mutex, checks the bool and then returns.

Answer (score 1):

This:

> ```
> m_acceptor.async_accept(m_socket, [this](boost::system::error_code error) { // Handler code });
> ```
>
> Handler code:
>
> ```
> std::condition_variable condition;
> std::mutex mutex;
> bool stopped(false);
> m_current_session->run(condition, mutex, stopped);
> {
>   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
>   condition.wait(lock, [&stopped] { return stopped; });
> }
> ```

Is strange. It suggests you are using an "async" accept, but the handler block unconditionally until the session completes. That's the opposite of asynchrony. You could much easier write the same code without the asynchrony, and also without the thread and synchronization around it.

My intuition says something is blocking the mutex. Have you established that the session stack is actually inside the `read_some` frame when e.g. doing a debugger break during a "lock-up"?

> When I manually close the socket the read_some method returns with error code so I know it is inside there I have an issue.

You can't legally do that. Your socket is in use on a thread - in a blocking read -, and you're bound to close it from a separate thread. That's a race-condition (see [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html#boost_asio.reference.ip__tcp.socket.thread_safety)). If you want cancellable operations, use `async_read*`.

There are more code smells (`read_some` is a lowlevel primitive that is rarely what you want at the application level, detached threads with manual synchronization on termination could be packaged tasks, shared boolean flags could be atomics, `notify_one` outside the mutex could lead to thread starvation on some platforms etc.).

If you can share more code I'll be happy to sketch simplified solutions that remove the problems.

Comment: Shouldn't the mutex raise an exception if it is reused in this setup? All reading is done inside session runner .run(args...) The runner holds the mutex during operations. When operations finish I let go of mutex i.e. exiting the scope and then signal condition variable. The con_var then locks the mutex and checks the bool.
I can't see where the code would get stuck

Comment: Just to be clear. I manually close the socket just as a test. It's not how it's done in the running code

Comment: I have added some description and more code Thank you for your time, @sehe

Comment: "Shouldn't the mutex raise an exception if it is reused in this setup?" - It's unclear what you mean. But no mutex doesn't throw. `unique_lock` [potentially](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/lock#Exceptions) throws but that would require you to share the actual instance, which you don't do.

Comment: "I can't see where the code would get stuck" - me neither, it wasn't in the code you showed.

Comment: I've combined the extra code into a working piece of code: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fc7892cb259b49d). But really, it would be much simpler: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/644d9e16b8992328 26 LoC less. But really, using more modern Asio and without the redundant blocking thread: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5905de5f64dfa1a4 - still functionally the same but way less complicated. All the reduced thread synchronization, shared state, socket instance(s), manual error checking leads to reduced opportunity for error.

Comment: Regarding the "raise an exception" I meant that "something will happen", my bad. The system(win32/64) FC the applickation if I were to reuse the mutex inside another lock while a lock is holding the mutex. I've tested this earlier.
I thank you for the simplified code. I'll keep it in mind.
For now I'm more into finding out why this is malfunctioning. 
This code is running on 50+ servers with much higher loads than the servers that are malfunctioning. Something is wrong, yes, but this code have been working for years and now suddenly starts missbehaving. And just on these 2 servers.

Comment: My take on this is to log all parameters from socket. If I cannot spot anything off I'll leave this code alone and wrap it inside an "alive-checker" that manually restarts communication when thread halts.
If you have any suggestions on what could go wrong and how I could retreive the parameter to log it I would be grateful.